# how to make blocking behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This may be a long or messy question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="plus"><img rc="/1.jpg""></div>
<div id="Welcome_button"><button type="button" class="centre" onclick="welcomeOnClicked()">Welcome</button></div>

<div id="question_set"></div>

<div id="answer_set">
<div id="answer1"><img src="/a1.jpg" onclick="answerSelected(1)"></div>
<div id="answer2"><img src="/a2.jpg" onclick="answerSelected(2)"></div>
<div id="answer3"><img src="/a3.jpg" onclick="answerSelected(3)"></div>
<div id="answer4"><img src="/a4.jpg" onclick="answerSelected(4)"></div>
<div id="answer5"><img src="/a5.jpg" onclick="answerSelected(5)"></div>
</div>
<iframe src="" id="hiddenIFrame"></iframe>

<script>
var random, block = 0;
var TimeToLive;
var questionImages;
var resoursePrefix = "some google drive link";`

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("question_set").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("answer_set").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("hiddenIFrame").style.display = "none";

//preload images
questionImages = new Array();
    function preload() {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            questionImages[i] = new Image();
            questionImages[i].src = preload.arguments[i+1];
        }
    }
    preload(
        resoursePrefix + "1.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "2.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "3.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "4.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "5.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "6.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "7.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "8.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "9.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "10.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "11.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "12.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "13.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "14.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "15.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "16.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "17.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "a1.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "a2.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "a3.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "a4.jpg",
        resoursePrefix + "a5.jpg"
    )
}, false);


function welcomeOnClicked() {
    document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Welcome_button").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("answer_set").style.display = "block";
    manageTest();
}

function manageTest() {
    block++;
    TimeToLive = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4];
    switchPic();
}

function switchPic() {
    for (var i = 0, endRound = true; i < TimeToLive.length; i++) {
        if (TimeToLive[i] >= 1) {
            endRound = false;
        }
    }
    if (endRound == true) {
        manageTest();
    }
    if (block > 4) {
        alert("finish");
    }
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 17) + 2);
    console.log("switch " + random);
    if (TimeToLive[random-2] < 1) {
        return;
    }
    TimeToLive[random-2]--;
    $("#question_set").append(questionImages[random-2]);
    document.getElementById("question_set").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#question_set").children("img").remove();
        document.getElementById("question_set").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "block";
    }, 200);
}

function answerSelected(answer) {
    console.log("submit block: " + block + " Q: " + random + " ans " + answer);
    Url = "some google form"
        + "&entry.1685446105=" + block
        + "&entry.995279407=" + random
        + "&entry.1271192673=" + answer
        + "&submit=Submit";
    document.getElementById("hiddenIFrame").src = Url;
    document.getElementById("hiddenIFrame").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("hiddenIFrame").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "none";
    switchPic();
}
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, sorry for long code.
It basically first shows a welcome page including a plus sign and a welcome button as following.
[image: start]
Then, a photo test starts.
The test first shows a picture in only 200ms then switch back to a plus sign.
User can choose the most similar picture among 5 pictures below.
[image: question]
In 200ms
[image: answer]

What really bother me is the test looping.
The requirement is there is 4 rounds.
In each round, each picture (total = 16) will be shown 4 times in random order.
That makes 64 random pictures are shown in each round.
After each picture is shown for 4 times, another round starts.

My first idea is to just loop the switchPic() to do that.
But I found there is no blocking in the function so the test just ends right away.
My second idea is the code above.
The problem is the function call in manageTest().
It makes the result / looping incorrect.

Extra information:
variable: random for storing the random number generated and call a picture to be shown. Then it is sent to google form.
block = round, 4 rounds in a test
TimeToLive is a array storing times to show each picture
In answerSelected(int), it sends results including round, picture drawn and response to google form using a hidden iframe.

Again, much appreciate for any input.
And welcome to point out any bad practice in the lines

Comment: I have read through your question and it is indeed a long one. In order to attract people to help you, you would have to simplify your problem a bit as you are asking a plethora or things and they all compound to make this harder...

Answer (score 0):

To make things happen after a period of time, you have the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions, which will call a function you give them after a delay you give them.

To keep track of what should happen when your function is called back, use variables.

Here's an example that simply counts from 1 to 10 at half-second intervals:

```js
var counter = 0;
tick();
function tick() {
    ++counter;
    console.log(counter);
    if (counter < 10) {
        setTimeout(tick, 500);
    }
}
```

This line:

```
setTimeout(tick, 500);
```

asks the browser to call the `tick` function after 500ms (half a second). The timing won't be precise, but it's usually good enough if the user doesn't switch to a different tab.

Then I'm just using `counter` to keep track of where I am.

Comment: sorry man, the problem is not the timeout. If you look at my codes, you will find settimeout also. The problem is after a call to switch picture, I have no pre information to know when will the user choose the answer picture

Comment: @user3042713: That's where *variables* come in.

Comment: watch a variable or using a while loop to check the variable?

Comment: @user3042713: Look at the example above again. You wouldn't need to *watch* the variable, just check it at the appropriate times. You certainly wouldn't need a `while` loop.